# Pallet Fails to Build Because of `std` Macros

Tags: pallet, frame, substrate-node-template, no-std

I am currently facing this Error:

```
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.62.0-nightly (e85edd9a8 2022-04-28)

     Compiling frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.19#174735ea)
  error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
    --> /home/creestl/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/174735e/frame/support/src/traits/storage.rs:77:17
     |
  77 |         let mut res = vec![];
     |                       ^^^
     |
     = note: consider importing one of these items:
             codec::alloc::vec
             crate::sp_std::vec
             scale_info::prelude::vec
             sp_std::vec
```

(it says that `std` macro is used when building for `no-std`)
The `frame-support` import in my `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }

***snip***

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "parity-scale-codec/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "frame-benchmarking/std",
]
```

So I **did not** modify any code of that pallet. It **is not** some kind of custom pallet. This code above is **from** substrate-node-template.

To build a node I use `cargo build --release` command.

I know that runtime builds in `no-std`. But I haven't had such error with that pallet before.

**[UPD]** I get the same error with finality-grandpa as well

```
error: cannot find macro `format` in this scope
    --> /home/creestl/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/174735e/primitives/finality-grandpa/src/lib.rs:43:2
     |
  43 |     app_crypto!(ed25519, GRANDPA);
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: consider importing one of these items:
             alloc::format
             scale_info::prelude::format
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_public_common_if_std` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Please assist. I've been trying to fix this for several days now.

Comment: What did you modify about your project? Did you make sure to add the `std` feature to any imported crates?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to implement PoW (smth like Kulupu's but more simple) on top of node template. I've added [primitives](https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/tree/master/primitives), [difficulty](https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/tree/master/frame/difficulty) pallets and one more pallet with my custom Sha256 PoW logic. 
I doublechecked that each crate's `std` is listed in `[features]`

Comment: The error here is almost certainly due to some missing feature stuff. I would start with the base node-template, and make changes one by one, checking each time it compiles.

Comment: That would be the best solution, but it would take me too much time to go back to the start and do the same steps once again:( That's why I'm trying to fix it the other way.

Comment: Strange, I am getting the same `error: cannot find macro 'format' in this scope` when doing a `cargo check` in my runtime folder.  this started after I added a new pallet to my runtime, and updated the versions in the `cargo.toml` in the runtime. definitely a dependency problem, still trying to figure it out.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. First let me explain how I got this error. I cloned Kulupu's [difficulty](https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/tree/master/frame/difficulty) pallet. And it required Kulupu's [primitives](https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/tree/master/primitives) as one of the dependencies. So I cloned them as well so the Cargo.toml dependencies section of my `primitives` crate looked like this:

```
[dependencies]
parity-scale-codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
sp-core = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }
sp-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }
```

But building the runtime failed with [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/10767) `wasm32` kind of error. First to fix this error I added the following to the Cargo.toml of my `primitives` crate:

```
getrandom = {version = "0.2", features= ["js"] }
```

So it's dependencies section looked like this:

```
[dependencies]
parity-scale-codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
sp-core = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }
sp-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }
getrandom = {version = "0.2", features= ["js"] }
```

Then I tried to build runtime again. At **this** point I got the `std` macros bug described in my question above.

The **solution** was pretty simple (even though I spent a *week* figuring it out):

- Deleted all unused dependencies from the Cargo.toml of my `primitives` crate. That fixed the `wasm32` error and thus made the `getrandom = {version = "0.2", features= ["js"] }` line useless as well. To be more specific, the `sp-api = { version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }` line was causing some inner conflict. So I could have deleted only this one, but I decided to get rid of everything that was unused. After that the runtime *built fine*.
  Final contents of Cargo.toml of my primitives crate:

```
***snip***

[dependencies]
sp-core = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19" }

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "sp-core/std", 
]
```